# Comparing Lists with Ellipsis in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, comparison, ellipsis

Is there any way to compare lists that reference themselves in Python? You can see what I've tried below:

```
In[65]:  b
Out[65]: [[...]]

In[66]:  a
Out[66]: [[[[...]]]]

In[67]:  a==b

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-67-67c639108cf0>", line 1, in <module>
    a==b

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

I can understand that it cannot keep going into the list forever, but is there still a way to compare lists that have Ellipsis?

[EDIT]:

How `a` was created:

```
a=[]
a.append(a)
a=[[[a]]]
```

How `b` was created:

```
b=[]
b.append(b)
b=[b]
```

Comment: Is that nested lists? Or literally a list of ellipsis nested inside a bunch of lists?

Comment: Please show how these lists were created.

Comment: Ok, will edit question.

Comment: They don't *contain* ellipsis, they are an infite list that contains itself. No, you can't

Comment: The `...` notation here represents a self-nested object, not the `Ellipsis` object that `...` evaluates to in Python code. The `Ellipsis` object would show up as `Ellipsis`.

Comment: Is there still a way to compare the two lists?

Comment: Ahh I see, a list that contains itself... `l = []; l.append(l)`

Comment: What exactly were you trying to compare? Both lists are obviously different, what is your goal here?

Comment: I am trying to compare the two lists. I think they should be the same because they both have infinite levels of nesting

Comment: Not true. They are contained within lists of different nesting level, so there is no way they are the same

Comment: Come up with a precise definition of when you want two recursively nested lists to be considered equal, and you'll be most of the way towards figuring out how to perform the comparison you want.

Comment: `a` is a kind of recursive list. Is there a real use case here? Or you are just  experimenting???

Comment: Just experimenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) and a generator based on list comprehension we can achieve a `compare` function that works on every case I could figure out:

```
def compare(list1: list, list2: list, root1=None, root2=None):
    """Compare recursively nested lists."""
    root1, root2 = (root1, root2) if root1 and root2 else (list1, list2)
    return len(list1) == len(list2) and all(
        ((a, b) == (root1, root2) or a == b)
        and compare(list1[i + 1:], list2[i + 1:], root1, root2)
        for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(list1, list2)))
```

### Examples

For comprehensibility sake I'll write the lists as they are represented when printed instead that building them constantly with `appends`.

```
a, b = ([[...]], [[...]])
compare(a, b)
>>> True

a, b = ([[...], 2], [[...]])
compare(a, b)
>>> False

a, b = ([2, [...], 2], [[...]])
compare(a, b)
>>> False

a, b = ([2, [...], 2], [2, [...], 2])
compare(a, b)
>>> True

a, b = ([2, [...], [2]], [2, [...], [3]])
compare(a, b)
>>> False
```

*If you'd like for me to test and add more cases I'll happily do it.*